# Back and forth. Navigate back, forth

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, syntactic-analysis

I am aware of the following expression

```
Back and forth
```

Basically that means to move in one direction and in the opposite one.

I wonder, whether is it possible to say the following

`This button can be used to navigate forth` ?

But I am sure that the following sentence is correct.

`This button can be used to navigate back` ?

I am not sure about the `forth` word only.

I would be grateful for any explanation.

Thanks

Comment: "Back and forth" is an idiomatic expression. Corresponding to "This button can be used to navigate back", we need to say "This button can be used to navigate **forward**," instead.

Comment: "Back and forth" can mean "left and right". Depends on the context.  Windshield wipers go back and forth.

Comment: It depends on context. If you're making a faux-medieval game, saying something like "Press yonder button to venture forth!" might be appropriate, but for modern usage, it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic phrase *back and forth* often means the same thing as *backward and forward* (not always; if you say *we bounced ideas back and forth*, it's a metaphorical usage where *backward* and *forward* would sound odd).

However, in general, while the words *forth* and *forward* are related, they don't have exactly the same meaning.

The [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/forth) defines *forth* as

> Out and away from a starting point. *‘we rose at dawn and sallied forth’*

and *forward* as

> In the direction that one is facing or travelling; towards the front.
>   *‘he started up the engine and the car moved forward’*

So in

> The light beamed forth from the lighthouse,

you can't replace *forth* by *forward* because the light is beaming out in all directions from the lighthouse, and not just forward.

And in

> my car's gearshift is broken; it only goes forward,

you can't replace *forward* by *forth* because there's no starting point that the car is going forth from. If you said *it only goes forth*, it would mean that you could drive your car away from your house in the morning, but you couldn't drive it back again at night. (A very strange mechanical problem for a car.)

So, in the OP's phrase,

> this button can be used to navigate forth,

*forth* should be replaced by *forward*.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing ungrammatical about [**forth**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forth):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : onward in time, place, or order : FORWARD · from that day *forth*
>
> He went *forth* to spread the news.

It is less commonly used than *forward*, and it might sound a little strange to some ears, but it's certainly not wrong.